# Is it possible to use sql join to receive an employees office property like one can do with linq include using asp.net mvc and entity framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a mvc model Employee that has a property Office.

Is it possible to use sql join to receive an employees office property like one can do with linq include using asp.net mvc and Entity Framework?

```
public partial class Employee
{

    public virtual Office Office { get; set; }
}


public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetBySql(string sql) 
{                     
    var  result = context.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>(sql).ToList();

    return result;
}

Select * From Employees 
INNER JOIN Offices
ON Employees.OfficeId=Offices.OfficeId

When using above sql i receive null in Office
```

Comment: yes, this is what EF does under the covers.  what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: You need to provide a bit more info (edit your question, don't add a comment): from where are you executing that sql statement, where do you want that "office property"?

Comment: i run the sql with join but the property is null in the result.

Comment: tell me if you need more info

Comment: please post your sql code as well, along with a sample of results you get, and a sample of results you WANT

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you are running a raw sql, so EF won't create a Office for you, I recommend you have a OfficeId in your Employee class, and get that value from your sql, and use OfficeId to get Office object.

If you want to use EF to get the Office object, you probably want to use context to get Employee by including Office properties

```
context.Set<Employee>().Include(e=>e.Office).Where(your predicate here)
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about the Include method, but that's not what I want here. I want to use raw sql to produce the same result if that's possible.

Comment: I don't think so, EF is the framework to materialize your object, if you bypass EF to use Raw SQL, I don't think you have a good way to do it.